# Calculate Tree Height at each Node, help me explain this code solution

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here's a code snippet of a solution that calculates height of each node in a binary tree and stores the height in each node. The code traverse the tree recursively, and below is the `Node` constructor.

```
class Node {
public:
  int height; // to be set by computeHeight()
  Node *left, *right;
  Node() { height = -1; left = right = nullptr; }
  ~Node() {
    delete left;
    left = nullptr;
    delete right;
    right = nullptr;
  }
};
```

Below is the function which computes and stores height at each `Node`. Where I am confused is how do `leftHeight` and `rightHeight` get updated by `n->left->height` and `n->right->height` if at construction, `height` is set to `-1`?

```
void computeHeight(Node *n) {

if (n == nullptr) {
    return;
}

computeHeight(n->left);
computeHeight(n->right);

int leftHeight = -1;
int rightHeight = -1;

if (n->left != nullptr) {
    leftHeight = n->left->height;
}

if (n->right != nullptr) {
    rightHeight = n->right->height;
}

n->height = std::max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
```

}

Here is the main file that runs the function `computeHeight`

```
int main() {
  Node *n = new Node();
  n->left = new Node();
  n->right = new Node();
  n->right->left = new Node();
  n->right->right = new Node();
  n->right->right->right = new Node();
  n->right->right->right->left = new Node();

  computeHeight(n);

  delete n;
  n = nullptr;

  return 0;
```

}

Comment: `n->height = std::max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;` -- See the `+ 1`?  What effect will that have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a leaf node (left and right are nullptr). Then `n->left != nullptr` and `n->right != nullptr` are false so the calculation effectively becomes

```
int leftHeight = -1;
int rightHeight = -1;
n->height = std::max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
```

which is effectively

```
n->height = 0;
```

Now because of the way the recursion is done, each node gets it height calculated **after** it's children have had their heights calculated. So imagine a node with two children, each of which is a leaf node. We've already seen that leaf nodes get a height of zero. So the calculation for such a node is effectively

```
int leftHeight = -1;
int rightHeight = -1;
if (n->left != nullptr) {
    leftHeight = 0; // because n->left is a leaf node
}
if (n->right != nullptr) {
    rightHeight = 0; // because n->right is a leaf node
}
n->height = std::max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
```

which means that you end up with `n->height = 1` for that node.

And so on. These calculations perculate up the tree, starting at the leaves, until finally the root gets it's height set.

Comment: can you add explanation for how the function starts at the bottom and percolate up? I've always assumed that `n->left` or `n->right` travels down and not up, and the `computeHeight` function takes `n` which is the root node which is conceptually at the top?

Comment: Look at the order in which things are done, it's 1) left recursive call, 2) right recursive call, 3) set height. So the recursion gets to the bottom (leaves) of the tree before any heights have been set. And for any node it's height gets set only after all it's descendents heights have bene set.

Comment: ah, after some scribbling and drawing on paper it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem with a basic case of induction. Basically, let's start with the base case, and then assuming any case `n` works, we have to check if case `n+1` works. In the case of calculating the heights of the nodes in a Binary Tree, the base case is when the root node is a leaf node, and for the `n+1` case the left/right side nodes are the `n` cases. You can think of it as n is the height of the current node, and `n=0` is the leaf node base case.

When the root node is a leaf, both the left and right side nodes are `nullptr` the method essentially turns into

```
void computeHeight(Node *n) {
    int leftHeight = -1;
    int rightHeight = -1;

    n->height = std::max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
}
```

in which case `n->height` becomes `0`, which is correct for a leaf node. Now, when the node is a non-leaf node, the statements

```
computeHeight(n->left);
computeHeight(n->right);
```

are already called before the calculation. This essentially makes it so that we assume that both the left and right side nodes are already taken care of, and their heights are correct. Then, we can use the left and right nodes' heights to calculate the root node's height, which is calculated through

```
int leftHeight = -1;
int rightHeight = -1;

if (n->left != nullptr) {
    leftHeight = n->left->height;
}

if (n->right != nullptr) {
    rightHeight = n->right->height;
}

n->height = std::max(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
```

The trick here is that we already have called `computeHeight()` on the left and right side nodes so that when we do the calculations on the current node, we can safely assume that the child nodes have been totally taken care of. Also, the child nodes are calculated before the root node, so the program will first trickle all the way down to the leaves before coming back up and calculating the non-leaf nodes.